# make bottom navigation views activity and when i run device manager it is not work

Tags: android-manifest, android-bottomnavigationview, android-device-manager

i make new acticity -->bottom navigation views activity. then i change in manifests intend from main to navigation. then i run in device manager but doesn work . message : NavigationActivity@4d842b7 does not have an ActionBar set via setSupportActionBar() at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcSdi.png)

expecting that it run in device manager